# What is potass?

Tags: meaning

I'm reading *The Four Feathers* by A.E.W.Mason, it contains a reference to a beverage consumed by one of the characters:-

> It would have been strange, after all, he thought, if he had not been
>   able to hoodwink poor old Durrance; and he returned to the smoking
>   room and refreshed himself with a *whisky and potass*.

This drink also features in other books; [here](http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/gutenberg.org/2/0/2/8/20280/20280.txt), for instance.

Searching for *potass* turned up no matches, but references to *potash* and *potassium*, neither of which (I would have thought) would be desirable ingredients in a cocktail.

So, what is *potass*?

Comment: Just a quick net search and I find it is older pharmaceutical nomenclature for potash/ potassium, as you mention. See http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/potass and https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/potass for examples.

Comment: @cobaltduck, I didn't turn up either of those references. Grrr. I suppose it is the potassium analogue to _whisky and soda_ (still not sure why you want that in your whisky, though).

Comment: On digging deeper, it seems like it *might* be, more specifically, one of the various salts of potassium, possibly potassium chlorate or carbonate.  These have been used as disinfectants, diuretics, and even in the making of some spirits.  I can't find a hard reference, though.

Comment: I actually encountered a "low sodium club soda" which was, essentially, potass, i.e. carbonated water with potassium bicarbonate added. (Regular club soda is carbonated water with sodium bicarbonate added.)

Comment: It's basically a whiskey-and-soda: "Seltzer water and club soda are very similar, but there is a notable difference between the two. Unlike seltzer, mineral-like ingredients are added to club soda to enhance the flavor. If you look on the list of ingredients, you'll likely see **potassium bicarbonate and potassium sulfate** listed." --[*Huffington Post*](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/10/29/seltzer-vs-club-soda_n_1434891.html)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary has *potass* from *potash*:

> An alkaline substance obtained originally by lixiviating or leaching the ashes of terrestrial vegetables and evaporating the solution in large iron pans or pots (whence the name). Chemically, this is a crude form of potassium carbonate (more or less mixed with sulphate, chloride, and empyreumatic substances), but was long thought to be (when freed from impurities) a simple substance.

And further defines it as:

> Used also to include the impure carbonate of soda, barilla. [Obscure]

*barilla* is defined as:

> An impure alkali produced by burning the dried [maritime plant barilla (*Salsola Soda*) which grows extensively in Spain, Sicily, and the Canary Islands]  and allied species; formerly imported in large quantities, and *used in the manufacture of soda* [...]

Emphasis mine.

So it's basically an old-time crude form of soda.

So he's having a (probably, by modern standards, quite **disgusting** and **strong**) *whisky and soda*.

The point the author might be making is it's not a lady's drink.  But something a **real man** would drink to "refresh" himself.  Perhaps with some intended irony.

Answer (score 24):

As indicated by @RobSter, Potass/Potass water/Kali potass was an sparkling acid beverage composed of water and nitrate salts, supposed to have medicinal virtues.

[image]

Source: *The new London dispensatory, containing a treaty of the Pharmacopœia* by Thomas Cox - 1824.

Comment: @anemone - Your remark is relevant. The potass water proposed as a drink may be similar to a Selzer water where the sodium bicarbonate is  replaced by potassium bicarbonate.

Answer (score 17):

The spelling of "whisky" sent me looking toward Britain.  From the *Aesclepiad Advertiser*, 1891, comes this advert from a firm of beverage bottlers in Croydon:

[image]

I suppose one could mix it with whisky. It seems to be a brutal thing to do to good whiskey, though.

*It's said that a certain Kentucky gentleman was asked why he always closed his eyes when drinking a mint julep. "Suh," he replied, "the sight of good liquor makes mah mouth water, and ah don't intend fo'  mah drink to be diluted..."*

Answer (score 1):

I believe, due to an affection for British Victorian-era fiction, that this is a "period" allusion to mixing a drink by using an old-fashioned "soda siphon;" not the current style of seltzer-bottle that is recharged using pressurized cylinders of carbon dioxide. Potassium bicarbonate---"potass"---and an acetic agent combined with water in the wire-reinforced "carboy" or bottle and provided the "fizz."

The chap had a "whisky and soda," in other words. (Cheers!)

At a time when taking one's liquor at room temperature was normal, putting a bit of fizz (and, probably, a slight "tang" in the water, from the acetic agent used to generate the bubbles of gas) in one's liquor was the "sophisticated" way to have a "mixed drink."

Answer (score 0):

There's a reference to 'whisky potass' in 'The Second Mrs Tanqueray' a play by A.W. Pinero, published in 1884. Probably a Victorian equivalent to a whisky and soda,which superseded it but is now out of fashion itself.